# How to modify my merge sort code to sort from biggest to smallest

Tags: python, sorting, merge

I know this is trivial but can't find my way around this.I have this merge sort code which sort from smallest to biggest, now i have been asked to modify the code to sort from biggest to smallest, but can't seem to find my way. Please any help will be appreciated thanks.

Here is the commented code:

```
def mergesort(lst):

    #Then, what does it do? mergesort should recursively
    #run mergesort on the left and right sides of lst until
    #it's given a list only one item. So, if lst has only
    #one item, we should just return that one-item list.

    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst

    #Otherwise, we should call mergesort separately on the
    #left and right sides. Since each successive call to
    #mergesort sends half as many items, we're guaranteed
    #to eventually send it a list with only one item, at
    #which point we'll stop calling mergesort again.
    else:

        #Floor division on the length of the list will
        #find us the index of the middle value.
        midpoint = len(lst) // 2

        #lst[:midpoint] will get the left side of the
        #list based on list slicing syntax. So, we want
        #to sort the left side of the list alone and
        #assign the result to the new smaller list left.
        left = mergesort(lst[:midpoint])

        #And same for the right side.
        right = mergesort(lst[midpoint:])


        #So, left and right now hold sorted lists of
        #each half of the original list. They might
        #each have only one item, or they could each
        #have several items.

        #Now we want to compare the first items in each
        #list one-by-one, adding the smaller to our new
        #result list until one list is completely empty.

        newlist = []
        while len(left) and len(right) > 0:

            #If the first number in left is lower, add
            #it to the new list and remove it from left
            if left[0] < right[0]:
                newlist.append(left[0])
                del left[0]

            #Otherwise, add the first number from right
            #to the new list and remove it from right
            else:
                newlist.append(right[0])
                del right[0]

        #When the while loop above is done, it means
        #one of the two lists is empty. Because both
        #lists were sorted, we can now add the remainder
        #of each list to the new list. The empty list
        #will have no items to add, and the non-empty
        #list will add its items in order.

        newlist.extend(left)
        newlist.extend(right)

        #newlist is now the sorted version of lst! So,
        #we can return it. If this was a recursive call
        #to mergesort, then this sends a sorted half-
        #list up the ladder. If this was the original
        #call, then this is the final sorted list.

        return newlist

#Let's try it out!
print(mergesort([2, 5, 3, 8, 6, 9, 1, 4, 7]))
```

This prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But am expected to print:

```
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply swapping `<` with `>` between `left[0]` and `right[0]` should do it if that wasn't obvious...

Comment: Am I supposed to believe you wrote that code and the explanations but aren't able to change `<` to `>`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann They didn't claim to have written it. This is obviously homework.

Answer (score 0):

You only make comparisons in one place in your code: during the merge, when you compare `left[0]` and `right[0]`. Reversing the sense of the comparison will reverse the overall sort. So to sort in *decreasing* order, add the *larger* of `left[0]` and `right[0]` to the output, i.e., if `left[0] > right[0]: newest.append(left[0])`.

Comment: @user8964866 - to preserve stability, the compare should be `left[0] >= right[0]` . If the elements are equal, you want to move the left element to preserve the original order on equal elements.